# launch or close apps on external triggers

Tags: ios, automation

In the current iOS SDK are there APIs that allow me do the follwing things?

**1) Lanch a certian application when**

a) I pass a geo-fence (e.g. arrive home)

b) I get logged in to a WiFi hotspot with a certain SSID

c) the device is plugged to a power source

**2) Close a certain application when**

a) I pass a geo-fence (e.g. leave home)

b) GPS/Geo/Location is turned off

c) WiFi is turned

d) I get logged out from a WiFI hotspot with a certain SSID

e) the device is unplugged from a power source

In case I missed it, is there any of the above things that iOS (6) itself can already do without the need of an extra app?

Comment: as far as I know, there is no way (at least, according to the guidelines) to close an app.

Comment: And I suppose the OS itself has no means to do any of the above things?

Answer (score 0):

Well yes and no.

The geofencing option will work on iOS 5 and higher. What you do is start monitoring a location with the [`CLLocationManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and call the [`startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3adesiredAccuracy%3a). Be sure to add background running support for location updates to your app, otherwise if the user backgrounds your app you wil not recieve any location changes. On recieving a location change you can then use [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to alert the user. 
But you do not have worry about start or closing the, the OS will handle this for you.

You can't detect changing state if your app iss't running, nor can you tell the OS to start your app when it start changing.

Detect WiFi is not really not possible, you can tell the OS that your can be used to login to WiFi network using a certain SSID. But I never tried it, but I known the FON and T-Mobile (European) app does this.